# Поиск слова в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть переменная

```
let string = "number:3, rank:2 ,value:7"
```

мне нужно найти в этой строке слово "rank" и получить идущие после него 3 символа

Comment: логичным бы было вроде получить значение `2`, зачем вам `:2 ` с двоеточием и пробелом ?

Comment: значения динамические и банально получить одно число не получится

Comment: ну вы все же опишите задачу в более общем случае и с примерами, вдруг у кого-то и получится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

с использованием регулярных выражений нахождение 3х символов из вашей задачи будет примерно следующим:

```js
let str = "number:3, rank:2 ,value:7";
let result = str.match(/rank(.{3})/i);
console.log( 'result = "' + result[1] + '"');
```

В случае, если требуется найти все-таки число, указанное после `rank:`, то

```js
let str = "number:3, rank:2112 ,value:7";
let result = str.match(/rank:(\d+)/i)
console.log( 'result = "' + result[1] + '"');
```

Если же потребуется найти произвольную последовательность между `rank:` до `,`, тогда

```js
let str = "number:3, rank:21qwe2 ,value:7";
let result = str.match(/rank:([^,]*?)\s*,/i)
console.log( 'result = "' + result[1] + '"');
```

Comment: спасибо огромное)